# How to switch to a different Java version on ideone?

Tags: ideone

I've created a free account on https://ideone.com/ and while setting up my account, I chose Java version-12 as the default version. However, I want to try running my code with different versions of Java but I do not see an option to switch versions. In fact, this (ability to switch to different versions) was the motivation for me to use **ideone**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option under 'others' to switch to a Java 8 compiler:

[image]

I'm not sure if other versions of Java are available.

Comment: Thanks, @Glorfindel for the helpful answer. Unfortunately, there is no way to switch to other versions like Java-11 (which is currently quite popular) or a version > 12. However, your answer is spot on.